# Is there a design pattern for this

Tags: design-patterns

I have the following domain, a dossier with documents:

```
-Dossier(Name,Documents[])
-Document(Name)
```

Now there is a new requeriment for a few dossiers which have subjects and each subject has documents, so the new domain would be like this:

```
-Dossier(Name,Subjects[])
-Subject(Number,Documents[])
-Document(Name)
```

For these few dossiers (7%) , I have to change a simple design for a more complex design. My question is: There is a design pattern or any idea which I can use for support the subjects but avoiding to change the initial domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

You may also find the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) or the [Delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) useful here.

Answer (score 1):

You can just keep references/links from Dossier to **both** collection of *Subjects* **and** collection of *Documents* (so it would be  -Dossier(Name,Documents[],Subjects[]) ) and implement some validation rules on DB/Programming language level like: when collection of *Subjects* is not empty in a *Dossier*, this dossier cannot have any *Documents* (colleciton of *Documents* must be empty). This way you change your model only *additively* without actually modyfing or removing anything existing.

Alternatively you can create a base class *Dossier* which has name and two subclasses: *DossierWithSubject* (with collection of subjects) and *DossierWithoutSubject* (with collection of  Documents) where the latter is exactly what you had so far. So just make / treat your current Dossiers as DossiersWithoutSubject.

Hope anything of this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to consider when choosing a pattern

If the design changes dynamically acording to a context which is external to Dossier consoder **Delegation** pattern ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)).

If this should be set during a "construction" or "initialization" stage you can consider a **pimpl** ([www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/PIMPL.aspx)) or **Decorator** ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)) pattern

Or maybye you need something different...

The choosen solution should depend on the exact problem that you need to solve. 
Two simple rules are:

1. Favor composition in place of inheritance
2. Encapsulate the variability

1) Means delegate to work to a components. Each cpmponent should do a "one thing" but do it good.

2) Means if there is a part in your system that is subject to change - encapsulete it in a seperate entity(ies)

For an **introduction** material in design patterns I could recomend tyou the "gang of four" book" [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)